# How can you solve this definitive integral $\int_{0}^{\ln(2)} \frac{x} {1+e^{-x}} dx $

Tags: integration

$$\int_{0}^{\ln(2)} \frac{x} {1+e^{-x}} dx $$ I have no clue how to start other than to  rearrange the expression and then trying to substitute  but it gets me nowhere .( at the deminator it it e to the power of -x)[image]

Comment: Are you familiar with dilogarithms? What do you get after the substitution $e^x=t$?

Comment: You can express it in polylogarithms.

Comment: I am actually in high school , i am preparing for a exam for university . This problem is for the exam preparation.

Comment: So i am assuming that there must be a simpler way to solve it .

Comment: There must be a typo then..

Comment: I can post a picture with it.

Comment: A picture might help. Also do you have the final answer by any chance?

Comment: I've posted the picture . It is actually a sum of two integrals

Comment: And you have options underneath

Comment: Well, now it becomes quite simple. You actually posted an [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info/) as you don't need to calculate explicitly both integrals. Again, What do you get after the substitution $e^x=t$?

Comment: Integrate by parts and substitute $u=e^{-x}, then do partial fractions and solve the integrals

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**: The first step here is to get the two integrals to have the same limits of integration:

$$I_1=\int_0^{\ln2}{x\over1+e^{-x}}dx=\int_1^2{\ln u\over1+u}du$$

and

$$I_2=\int_{\ln2}^{\ln3}{x\over1-e^{-x}}dx=\int_1^2{\ln(u+1)\over u}du$$

using $x=\ln u$ in the first substitution and $x=\ln(u+1)$ in the second. Now integrate $I_1$ by parts and see what happens. (Mouse over the box below to see the result.)

> $$I_1=\int_1^2{\ln u\over1+u}du=\ln u\ln(1+u)\big|_1^2-\int_1^2{\ln(1+u)\over u}du=\ln2\ln3-I_2$$

The take-home lesson is that it's not necessary to compute either integral explicitly; the problem has been artificially constructed to be solvable using a trick.

Comment: Awesome ! Thank you !