# Calculus 2: Integration by Parts Stuck on Integral of Product With ArcTan Inside

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm stuck on the following problem:

$$\int_0^{1/3} y \tan^{-1}(3y)\,dy$$

I think my last line in my work below is correct but I don't know what to do beyond that.

A step through of the problem would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: $$ \frac{y^2}{1 + 9 y^2} = \frac19 \frac{1 + 9 y^2}{1 + 9 y^2} - \frac19 \frac{1}{1 + 9y^2} $$

Comment: how did you come up with that?  is there a formula that indicates this?

Comment: Have you learned, in your calculus class, how to integrate rational functions? If so, did you notice that $y^2 / (1 + 9y^2)$ is an _improper_ rational function that requires polynomial long division first?

Comment: no ... I googled online as well but couldn't find the specific thing I'm looking for; mind sending me a link so I can brush up on this?  speicifically, an example very close to mine

Comment: Typically partial fractions and integration of rational functions is part of the Calc II curriculum. If you haven't gotten to it yet, you will soon.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x = 3y$ then  $ 3dy = dx $,

$$\displaystyle \int_0 ^{\frac {1}{3}} y \ \tan^{-1}(3y) dy = \frac {1}{9} \int_0 ^1 x\ \tan^{-1}(x) dx$$

Use **ILATE**

$\displaystyle \Rightarrow  \frac {1}{18} [x^2 \tan^{-1}(x) |_0 ^1  - \int_0 ^1 \frac {x^2}{1+x^2} dx ]   $

$\displaystyle \Rightarrow  \frac {1}{18} [x^2 \tan^{-1}(x) |_0 ^1  - \int_0 ^1 \frac {x^2}{1+ x^2} dx ]   $

$\displaystyle \Rightarrow  \frac {1}{18} [x^2 \tan^{-1}(x) |_0 ^1  - ( \int_0 ^1 dx - \int_0 ^1  \frac {1}{1+ x^2} dx )] $

$\displaystyle \Rightarrow  \frac {1}{18} [x^2 \tan^{-1}(x) - x + \tan^{-1}(x) ]_0 ^1   $

$\displaystyle \Rightarrow  \frac {1}{18} [(x^2 + 1) \tan^{-1}(x) - x  ]_0 ^1   
 = \frac {\pi}{36} - \frac {1}{18}$

Please tell if there are errors in this, because I haven't studied calculus yet.

Comment: The last step is incorrect since $\displaystyle\int\dfrac{1}{1+\frac{1}{x^2}} \color{red}{\neq \arctan\left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right)+C}$.

Comment: Ok, I am trying some other way (partial fractions). I will correct it.

Answer (score 1):

Integrate by parts $\left(f = \tan^{-1}3y, g' = y \Rightarrow f' = \frac{3}{9y^2 + 1}, g = \frac{y^2}{2}\right)$:

$$\int y \tan^{-1}(3y) dy$$
$$= \frac{y^2 \tan^{-1}(3y)}{2} - \int \frac{3y^2}{2(9y^2 + 1)} dy$$
$$= \frac{y^2 \tan^{-1}(3y)}{2} - \frac{3}{2} \int \frac{y^2}{9y^2 + 1} dy$$

Write $y^2$ as $\frac{1}{9}(9y^2+1) - \frac{1}{9}$ then we get:

$$\frac{y^2 \tan^{-1}(3y)}{2} - \frac{3}{2} \int \frac{\frac{1}{9}(9y^2+1) - \frac{1}{9}}{9y^2 + 1} dy$$
$$= \frac{y^2 \tan^{-1}(3y)}{2} - \frac{3}{2} \int \frac{\frac{1}{9}(9y^2+1)}{9y^2 + 1} - \frac{\frac{1}{9}}{9y^2 + 1}dy$$
$$= \frac{y^2 \tan^{-1}(3y)}{2} - \frac{3}{2} \int \frac{1}{9} - \frac{1}{9} \frac{1}{9y^2 + 1}dy$$
$$= \frac{y^2 \tan^{-1}(3y)}{2} - \frac{1}{6} \int 1 - \frac{1}{9y^2 + 1}dy$$
$$= \frac{y^2 \tan^{-1}(3y)}{2} - \frac{1}{6} \left(\int 1\,dy - \int \frac{1}{9y^2 + 1}dy\right)$$

Using substitution $u=3y$, we get:

$$= \frac{y^2 \tan^{-1}(3y)}{2} - \frac{1}{6} \left(\int 1\,dy - \frac{1}{3} \int \frac{1}{u^2 + 1}du\right)$$
$$= \frac{y^2 \tan^{-1}(3y)}{2} - \frac{1}{6} \left(y - \frac{1}{3} \tan^{-1}u + C\right)$$
$$= \frac{y^2 \tan^{-1}(3y)}{2} - \frac{1}{6} y + \frac{1}{18} \tan^{-1}3y + C$$
$$= \frac{(9y^2 + 1) \tan^{-1}(3y) - 3y}{18} + C$$

Now you can evaluate the integral:

$$\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{3}} y \tan^{-1}(3y) \, dy = \frac{\pi - 2}{36}$$

Comment: $Definite \ integrals \ can \ be \ converted \ to \ any \ form \ but \ it \ is \ not \ the \ case \ with \ indefinite  \ integrals - $ I was also not aware about until someone responded to my solution in which I did the same conceptual error.

Comment: Why? Aren't we having the same answer? His respond was $\int \frac{1}{1 + \frac{1}{x^2}} \neq tan^{-1}(\frac{1}{x})$, but I wasn't having that in my solution.

Comment: Not this solution. That solution was to some other question. He told me that many times the answer would be different. He did some calculation in which he used it and converted the indefinite integral back to definite which got his answer completely different.

Comment: [Link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3562178/how-can-you-solve-this-definitive-integral-int-0-ln2-fracx-1e-x/3562245#3562245)

Comment: @NikolaAlfredi OK I got it

Answer (score 0):

Intrgrate by parts taking $y$ as first function:
$$I=\int_{0}^{1/3} y \tan^{-1}(3y) ~dy=\tan^{-1}(3y) (y^2/2)|_{0}^{1/3}-\int_{0}^{1/3} \frac{3}{1+9y^2} \frac{y^2}{2} dy=\frac{\pi}{72}--\frac{1}{18}+\frac{1}{6} \int_{0}^{1/3} \frac{dy}{1+9y^2}= \frac{\pi}{72}-\frac{1}{18}+\frac{\pi}{72}$$
$$\implies I=\frac{\pi}{36}-\frac{1}{18}$$